# Are there any plans to implement further data types in ArangoDB with VelocityPack?

Tags: arangodb

Currently numbers are stored as 64bit binary, both for floating points and integers: are there any plans to implement integers and other data (such as binary data) natively in ArangoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Velocypack was invented with these future extending of datatypes in mind.

However, before adding more datatypes the following questions need to be answered first:

- howto spread the implementation of the extension over all parser implementations
- howto best make drivers understand it
- howto manipulate (compare, etc.) them in AQL
- howto index them
- howto represent them in the web-UI which is talking json to the server
- howto save them from the webui without destroying them in the original document

Once we have good answers to these questions, i.e. date types or higher precision float types may be introduced.